# linux ftp server log file to include additional information

Tags: linux, ftp

I am implementing the ftp server on linux box (fedora 11, vsftpd). Everything works good so far but i need Ftp server log files to contain transfer rate information.

At the moment when I use "get " or " put" command from client end , I got following message on ftp client

example

> ftp: 18 bytes received in 0.00seconds 18000.00kbytes/sec.

Is there is any way , I can get same message on ftp server side?

Below is the sample of my xferlog file

```
Tue Oct 23 01:28:52 2012 1 10.65.112.55 1 /home/test/testfile b _ o r test ftp 0 * c 
Tue Oct 23 01:32:46 2012 1 10.65.112.55 18 /home/test/uploadServer b _ i r test ftp 0 * c 
Tue Oct 23 01:50:23 2012 1 192.168.10.27 1 /home/test/testfile a _ o r test ftp 0 * c 
Tue Oct 23 01:50:36 2012 1 192.168.10.27 19 /home/test/test a _ i r test ftp 0 * c
```

Comment: Do you really 'implement' an ftp server, or do you install or configure an existing implementation? If so, which software is it that you are using as server? Because you will have to check the features of that ftp server.

Comment: sorry for not so clear .. I have installed ftp package vsftpd-2.2.2-6.fc12.i686.rpm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I really appreciate everyone's help here. 
 Well I have solved that.
 I have included 
***dual_log_enable= yes*** in the vsftpd.conf file and as a result it created the new log file  as /var/log/vsftpd.log  and it contains all the information that I need.